# find out data set for terminal nodes in regression tree

Tags: r

I generated a regression tree, and now i need to do a stepwise regression in each terminal node. BUT when i try to run the following code every time i get the following error message. Can anybody please help me how to find the data set for each terminal node?

```
library(XLConnect)
data1=loadWorkbook("trb88.xlsx", create = FALSE)


dat = readWorksheet(data1, sheet="Sheet1")

fit=lm(totalseverity~sl+lw+ntl+aadtln+s+med+osp+cbd+segl+fc+ow,data =dat)

library(rpart)


rp1 = rpart(factor(totalseverity)~sl+lw+ntl+aadtln+s+med+osp+cbd+segl+fc+ow,dat=dat,method="anova")

cv.rpart(rp1)

printcp(rp1)

tn1_1=rownames(table(as.matrix(rp1$where))) #Index TN


df_1=as.data.frame(rp1[["frame"]])  #Find TN

tn2_1=rownames(df_1[as.numeric(tn1_1),])  #Find TN

d1=list()  #Data

d1[[i]]=dat[cases.tree(rp1,tn2_1),c(1:11,12)]
```

error message is

`"Error in [.data.frame(dat, cases.tree(rp1, tn2_1), c(1:11, 12)) : 
  could not find function "cases.tree""`

my data set contains 11 predictor variables and 1 response variable.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `cases.tree` is not part of an `R` package, but is instead included in [this R script](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~tpminka/courses/36-350.2001/code/tree.r) of helper functions to go along with the `tree` package. If you `source` the script (and you probably also need to load the `tree` package as well), you should be able to use the function without getting the "could not find function" error.

Comment: One correction: the script I linked to above takes care of loading the `tree` package, so you just need to make sure `tree` is installed on your system.